# How to create a TSQL conditional display query?

Tags: sql

I need help with the following query. I know this has something to with Case When statement but I'm having trouble completing the query without errors. This is what I have.

```
select * 
from tbl_mstr left outer join tbl_1
on tbl_mstr.dt = tbl_1.dt
left outer join tbl_2
on tbl_mstr.dt = tbl_2.dt
left outer join tbl_3
on tbl_mstr.dt = tbl_3.dt
```

Code:

Pulling data based on conditions and display warnings
You have a master table with date sensitive records.

You have 3 other child tables with associated records and volumes.

The three child tables house the same information but T1 is considered more accurate than T2 and it is considered more accurate than T3.
These tables may or may not have information for a given day.

Your task:

```
1. To pull all information from the master table
2.  Pull the most accurate volume in as a column (vol)
3.  Create a warning flag for all three child tables if the volume is over 50 or below -50
4.  Do this with the minimal amount of code
5.  No loops
6.  No sub queries
7.  No temp tables
```

*/

SET NOCOUNT ON;

```
DECLARE @tbl_mstr TABLE (id int, nm varchar(50), dt datetime)
DECLARE @tbl_1 TABLE (id int, dt datetime, vol float)
DECLARE @tbl_2 TABLE (id int, dt datetime, vol float)
DECLARE @tbl_3 TABLE (id int, dt datetime, vol float)

INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/1/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/2/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/3/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/4/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/5/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/6/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/7/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/8/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/9/2009')
INSERT @tbl_mstr VALUES(1,'Helga','10/10/2009')

INSERT INTO @tbl_1 VALUES(1,'10/2/2009',25)
INSERT INTO @tbl_1 VALUES(1,'10/8/2009',42)
INSERT INTO @tbl_1 VALUES(1,'10/9/2009',38)

INSERT INTO @tbl_2 VALUES(1,'10/1/2009',-55)
INSERT INTO @tbl_2 VALUES(1,'10/3/2009',69)
INSERT INTO @tbl_2 VALUES(1,'10/8/2009',74)
INSERT INTO @tbl_2 VALUES(1,'10/10/2009',16)

INSERT INTO @tbl_3 VALUES(1,'10/1/2009',08)
INSERT INTO @tbl_3 VALUES(1,'10/4/2009',37)
INSERT INTO @tbl_3 VALUES(1,'10/5/2009',75)
INSERT INTO @tbl_3 VALUES(1,'10/6/2009',-22)
INSERT INTO @tbl_3 VALUES(1,'10/7/2009',-64)
```

Results should look like this below:

```
id   nm       dt                           vol      T1_Flag     T2_Flag       T3_Flag
1    Helga    2009-10-01 00:00:00:00.000   -55      OK          T2 Wrng       Ok
1    Helga    2009-10-02 00:00:00:00.000    25      OK          Ok            Ok
1    Helga    2009-10-03 00:00:00:00.000    69      Ok          T2 Wrng       Ok
1    Helga    2009-10-04 00:00:00:00.000    37      Ok          Ok            Ok
1    Helga    2009-10-05 00:00:00:00.000    75      Ok          Ok            T3 Wrng
1    Helga    2009-10-06 00:00:00:00.000   -22      Ok          Ok            Ok    
1    Helga    2009-10-07 00:00:00:00.000   -64      Ok          Ok            T3 Wrng
1    Helga    2009-10-08 00:00:00:00.000    42      Ok          T2 Wrng       Ok
1    Helga    2009-10-09 00:00:00:00.000    38      Ok          Ok            Ok
1    Helga    2009-10-10 00:00:00:00.000    16      Ok          Ok            Ok
```

Comment: Why do people constantly tag sql-server questions with the mysql tag (and vice versa)? Two totally different databases.

Comment: you should show some effort to solve your task

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one uses `COALESCE` for the vol and `CASE` statement for the table flags.

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    m.nm,
    m.dt,
    vol = COALESCE(t1.vol, t2.vol, t3.vol),
    T1_Flag = CASE WHEN t1.vol > 50 OR t1.vol < -50 THEN 'T1 Wrng' ELSE 'Ok' END,
    T2_Flag = CASE WHEN t2.vol > 50 OR t2.vol < -50 THEN 'T2 Wrng' ELSE 'Ok' END,
    T3_Flag = CASE WHEN t3.vol > 50 OR t3.vol < -50 THEN 'T3 Wrng' ELSE 'Ok' END
FROM @tbl_mstr m
LEFT JOIN @tbl_1 t1 ON t1.id = m.id AND t1.dt = m.dt
LEFT JOIN @tbl_2 t2 ON t2.id = m.id AND t2.dt = m.dt
LEFT JOIN @tbl_3 t3 ON t3.id = m.id AND t3.dt = m.dt
```